# Python- Update txt file every time data appended to print

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, data-structures

Currently I'm doing my **first project** which consists on a program for restaurants.
To log in as a waiter/tres you insert your name and is added to a TXT file.

My problem is that in the code when I print the **TXT file** to see the users that **signed in** it won't show the **updated list** if not the original list.

```
snames = list()
f_n = (open('names.txt')).read()
print("Welcome to NAME.app")
try:
    while True:
        name = input("Please select waiter/tress NAME - ADD to save new name - LIST to see saved names:")
        if name.lower() == "add":
            n_input = input("Name:")
            with open('names.txt', 'a') as f:
                f.write(n_input + '\n')
            continue

        elif name.lower() == "list":
            print(f_n.split())

        elif name == snames:
            print("Logged as", name)#doubtful line. print name of list.


        elif name == "exit":
            exit()
except:
    print("Invalid input")
```

In the second **ELIF** is what I wrote to see saved names(users).
But as I said prints the TXT file without **including what I added** in the first **IF**.

This might help.

**OUTPUT**

```
Welcome to NAME.app
Please select waiter/tress NAME - ADD to save new name - LIST to see saved names:add
Name:Python
Please select waiter/tress NAME - ADD to save new name - LIST to see saved names:list
['Ale', 'Sarah', 'Annette', 'Dan']
Please select waiter/tress NAME - ADD to save new name - LIST to see saved names:
```

Appreciate recommendations and solutions.
thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first line you read all the names, only after that you added more names, so the f_n variable doesn't get updated.

Change the "list" option to this

```
elif name.lower() == "list":
    with open('names.txt') as f:
        print(f.read().splitlines())
```

This will make sure to read the updated list each time you choose this option

Comment: That works perfectly Ron, thank you. So that means that every time I want to update the data in file I have to reopen it, right? Again thank you very much.........

Welcome to NAME.app

 - Please select user NAME
 - ADD to save new user
 - LIST to see saved users
 - REMOVE to delete a user
 ...list
['Ale', 'Sarah', 'Annette']
 ...add
Name:Ron Serruya

 ...list
['Ale', 'Sarah', 'Annette', 'Ron Serruya']